# Docker container for Deep Learning with Python, Chollet

Tags: python-2.7, docker, keras, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm building a Docker container to run the example code in "Deep Learning with Python" by Francois Chollet and keep getting an Assertion Error while using `docker-compose up` in Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried updating PIP, Python and Docker-Compose

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-base-ubuntu16.04

# Pick up some TF dependencies

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        build-essential \
        cuda-command-line-tools-9-0 \
        cuda-cublas-9-0 \
        cuda-cufft-9-0 \
        cuda-curand-9-0 \
        cuda-cusolver-9-0 \
        cuda-cusparse-9-0 \
        libcudnn7=7.2.1.38-1+cuda9.0 \
        libnccl2=2.2.13-1+cuda9.0 \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libhdf5-serial-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libzmq3-dev \
        pkg-config \
        software-properties-common \
        unzip \
        && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install nvinfer-runtime-trt-repo-ubuntu1604-4.0.1-ga-cuda9.0 && \
        apt-get update && \
        apt-get install libnvinfer4=4.1.2-1+cuda9.0

ARG USE_PYTHON_3_NOT_2
ARG _PY_SUFFIX=${USE_PYTHON_3_NOT_2:+3}
ARG PYTHON=python${_PY_SUFFIX}
ARG PIP=pip${_PY_SUFFIX}

RUN echo "python version: $PYTHON"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ${PYTHON} \
    ${PYTHON}-pip

RUN ${PIP} install --upgrade \
    pip \
    setuptools

ARG TF_PACKAGE=tensorflow-gpu
RUN ${PIP} install ${TF_PACKAGE}

# COPY bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc
# RUN chmod a+rwx /etc/bash.bashrc

RUN ${PIP} install jupyter

RUN mkdir /notebooks && chmod a+rwx /notebooks
RUN mkdir /.local && chmod a+rwx /.local
WORKDIR /notebooks
EXPOSE 8888

RUN mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/data

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN ${PIP} install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD ["bash", "-c", "source /etc/bash.bashrc && jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/notebooks --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root"]
```

I expect this to open a Docker Container with a Jupyter Notebook that I can open in a web browser application but the error I'm getting is:

```
Step 20/21 : RUN ${PIP} install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in c9c41fa7e5c3
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting Pillow (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading 
Collecting keras (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading 
Collecting matplotlib (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading 
Collecting scikit-learn (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading 
Collecting scipy>=0.14 (from keras->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading 
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from keras->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from keras->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from keras->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.12.0)
Collecting pyyaml (from keras->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading 
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from keras->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-applications>=1.0.6 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from keras->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.0.6)
Collecting pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 (from matplotlib->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading 
Collecting backports.functools-lru-cache (from matplotlib->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading 
Collecting subprocess32 (from matplotlib->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading 
Collecting pytz (from matplotlib->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading 
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (2.7.5)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading 
Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading 
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (40.6.3)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 176, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 346, in run
    session=session, autobuilding=True
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/wheel.py", line 848, in build
    assert building_is_possible
AssertionError
You are using pip version 19.0, however version 19.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
ERROR: Service 'deep-learning-with-python_service' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ${PIP} install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Comment: it seems that pip is failing to install some of the requirements - could you please share a trace of the entire build command or just a few lines before the exception to understand which package fails to install?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in pip 19.0 See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6158

Downgrade to pip==18.1 (for now) or wait for a fix to be released.

Edit: Pip 19.0.1 was just released to fix this

Comment: I downgraded to pip==18.1 and still getting same error, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Try upgrading "You are using pip version 19.0, however version 19.0.1 is available."

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Docker was using a cached image to save time, must of had pip 19.0 in the cache. Once I cleared all the cached images it built and worked as expected.